# Using universal coverings to calculate fundamental group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I want to calculate the fundamental group of $T^*=(T\setminus\Delta)/\sim$ where

- $T$ is the torus.
- $\Delta$ is the diagonal
- $\sim$ is an equivalence relation defined by $(x,y)\sim (y,x)$

I want to do this without relying on the Seifert-Van Kampen Theorem, since the hint for the problem was to use lifts/universal coverings.

**My question is the following:** How would one approach a problem like this, using lifts/universal coverings?

I understand that we could find the univeral covering space $\widetilde{(T-\Delta)}$ and then use this to cover $T^*$ by composing $\widetilde{(T-\Delta)}\longrightarrow(T-\Delta)\longrightarrow T^*$, but I fail to see what this would say about the fundamental groups. Or perhaps this is the wrong approach.

I am beginner when it comes to topology and I find these types of problems  particularly difficult, so any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I have an abbreviated answer for you which is posted below. I may have lost my full answer, but I will come back and add more details later.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for a great answer, I understand things much better now. I am very sorry for accidentally deleting the question!

Comment: Heh, that's okay. Weird things happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the universal covering space and deck transformation group of the torus $T$, which I'm sure you know very well:
$$f : \mathbb R^2 \to T = (S^1)^2
$$
$$D_f = \mathbb Z^2 \quad\text{acting by translations on} \quad \mathbb R^2
$$
Of course, $D_f$ is isomrophic to $\pi_1(T)$.

The strategy is to use this well known information to carry out two steps:

Step 1. First, determine the universal covering space and deck transformation group for $T \setminus \Delta$.

Step 2. Second, determine the universal covering space and deck transformation group for $(T \setminus \Delta) / \sim$.

Of course, that second deck transformation group will be isomorphic to the fundamental group of $(T \setminus \Delta) / \sim$.

For Step 1, downstairs in $T$, we first remove the diagonal
$$\Delta = \{(x,x) \in (S^1)^2 \mid x \in S^1\}
$$ 
Upstairs in $\mathbb R^2$, we remove the "total lift" of the diagonal, which is
$\widetilde\Delta = f^{-1}(\Delta)$, and one can work that set out to be
$$\widetilde\Delta = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid y-x \in \mathbb Z\}
$$
in other words all lines of slope $1$ passing through integer points.

Now consider the following question: how, from the information just described, can we determine the universal covering space and deck transformation group of $T \setminus \Delta$?

Answer: First consider two consecutive components of $\widetilde\Delta$, let's say the lines $y=x$ and $y=x+1$. Then consider the strip of $\mathbb R^2 - \widetilde\Delta$ that lies between those two lines, i.e. the solution set of the inequality $x < y < x+1$. Let's denote that set 
$\widetilde{T - \Delta}$. This set is simply connected, and the restricted map
$$f : \widetilde{T - \Delta} \to T \setminus \Delta
$$
is a covering map, so it is a universal covering map.

Next, consider the subgroup of $D_f = \mathbb Z^2$ that takes the set $\widetilde{T - \Delta}$ to itself. That subgroup is the diagonal subgroup
$$D_{T-\Delta} = \{(k,k) \in \mathbb Z^2\}
$$
and it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. One can check that this is the deck transformation group of the map $\widetilde{T-\Delta} \mapsto T-\Delta$.

For step 2, which I'll cover more briefly, one proceeds similarly but this time with a quotient construction. $T^*$ is the quotient of $T-\Delta$ by the identification $(x,y) \sim (y,x)$. Its universal cover $\widetilde T^*$ is the quotient of $\widetilde{T-\Delta}$ by a quotient construction which one can work out is given by the formula $(x,y) \sim (y - \frac{1}{2},x+\frac{1}{2})$. Using this quotient one sees that $\widetilde T^*$ is homeomorphic to the half-strip $x < y \le x+\frac{1}{2}$ hence is simply connected. Using quotient map theory, one shows that there is an induced universal covering map $\widetilde T^* \to T^*$, and an induced action of $D_{T-\Delta}$ of $\widetilde T^*$ which is the deck transformation action of this map. Thus, $\pi_1(T^*)$ is isomorphic to $D_{T-\Delta} \approx \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Sorry just a final think I got a little bit stuck on. When you let $(x-y)\sim (y-\frac{1}{2},x+\frac{1}{2})$, that is basically $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acting on $\widetilde{T-\Delta}$, right? Then we have the usual deck transformation $\mathbb{Z}$. Why doesn't $\pi_1(T^*)$ become $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ in this case?

Comment: The $\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$ action on $\widetilde{T-\Delta}$ is not a free action, i.e. it is not a deck transformation actions. What that action does to  $\widetilde{T-\Delta}$ is essentially to "fold it in half" (or perhaps to "reflect it") across the line $y=x+\frac{1}{2}$; all points on that line are fixed by the action. The restriction of the quotient map $\widetilde{T-\Delta} \mapsto \widetilde T^*$ to the half-strip $x < y \le x + \frac{1}{2}$ ends up being a homeomorphism from that half-strip to the quotient space $T^*$.

Comment: I had a typo in my answer regarding the inequalities defining that half-strip.

Comment: Relevant to the question, but not an answer, is that there are results in Ch 11 (Orbit spaces, orbit groupoids) of my book "Topology and Groupoids", and one example is the computation under certain local condition of the    fundamental group  of the  symmetric square of a space. This is kind of development of covering space/covering groupoid  theory, and looks at groups acting on groupoids.